# How to get a projectile to shoot towards a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im currently working on a TurretAi. I have it so that when the enemy is within a certain range the turret targets the enemy but I'm unable to get the turret to shoot the projectiles toward the enemy. this is currently what i have this is turret class.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Defence : MonoBehaviour {

    public float DistanceFromCastle,CoolDown;
    public GameObject enemy;
    public GameObject Bullet;
    public int protectionRadius,bulletSpeed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        protectionRadius = 35;
        bulletSpeed = 50;
        CoolDown = 5;

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        enemy = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy");

        if(enemy != null)
        {
            DistanceFromCastle = Vector3.Distance(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Enemy").transform.position,GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Defence").transform.position);
            //print (DistanceFromCastle);
            if(DistanceFromCastle <= protectionRadius)
            {
                attackEnemy();
            }

        }
    }
    void attackEnemy()
    {
        transform.LookAt(enemy.transform);
        CoolDown -= Time.deltaTime;
        if (CoolDown <= 0)
        {

            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position,enemy.transform.position,Color.red);
            Instantiate(Bullet,Vector3.forward,Quaternion.identity);

            print("attack Enemy");
            CoolDown = 5;
        }
    }
}
```

I also already have a cool down var so that it only shoot every 5 second any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were fairly close, you need to change this line:

```
Instantiate(Bullet, Vector3.forward, Quaternion.identity);
```

To this:

```
private const int SPAWN_DISTANCE = 5;

Instantiate(Bullet, transform.position + SPAWN_DISTANCE * transform.forward, transform.rotation);
```

---

[Quaternion.identity](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion-identity.html) refers to:

> This quaternion corresponds to "no rotation".

Comment: When i change this, the bullet doesn't fire in the straight line from where the turret is looking

Comment: Does your turret have many parts? Don't tell me you rotate the top and the script is attached to the base.

Comment: I just have this attached to a cube and getting the cube to look at the object when its in range i want to shoot a projectile at it

Comment: This doesn't shoot in the current direction that the cube is facing

Comment: Even after the update i always shoots it in the same direction not where the gamobject is currenly facing

Comment: @user2552211 Last try, use the new version of the code.

Comment: Worked like a charm, i changed it a little i took the DistanceFrom castle var and placed that into the Spawn distance now it working just like i wanted to

Comment: **Question:** `Quaternion` corresponds to "no rotation", but what does `Quaternion.identity` correspond to then?